# Midrash about eshet potifar

Tags: agada-stories-legends, arizal

I heard in a shiur a midrash that the friends of Eshet Potiphar didn’t believe how beautiful a Jew like Joseph was, so she brought all her friends in a room, sat them in a circle and gave them knives and etrogim (food to eat), and then she brought Joseph in with some thing around his neck that prevented him from looking down. And then when the girls saw Joseph they began chopping their fingers because they were in such awe. And for a split second too, Joseph opened his eyes and caught a glimpse of Eshet Potifar (and therefore the Arizal explains that Joseph was reincarnated as Rabbi Yishmael Kohen Gadol and killed in such a gruesome way to make up for this)

So anyone know where I can find this midrash? Sounds like something right out of the Zohar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Midrash tanchuma parchat vayeshev 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma,_Vayeshev_5.2):

> אָמְרוּ רַבּוֹתֵינוּ זִכְרוֹנָם לִבְרָכָה: פַּעַם אַחַת נִתְקַבְּצוּ הַמִּצְרִיּוֹת וּבָאוּ לִרְאוֹת יָפְיוֹ שֶׁל יוֹסֵף. מֶה עָשְׂתָה אֵשֶׁת פּוֹטִיפַר, נָטְלָה אֶתְרוֹגִים וְנָתְנָה לְכָל אַחַת וְאַחַת מֵהֶן וְנָתְנָה סַכִּין לְכָל אַחַת וְאַחַת, וְקָרְאָה לְיוֹסֵף וְהֶעֱמִידַתּוּ לִפְנֵיהֶן. כֵּיוָן שֶׁהָיוּ מִסְתַּכְּלוֹת בְּיָפְיוֹ שֶׁל יוֹסֵף, הָיוּ חוֹתְכוֹן אֶת יְדֵיהֶן. אָמְרָה לָהֶן, וּמָה אַתֶּן בְּשָׁעָה אַחַת כָּךְ. אֲנִי שֶׁבְּכָל שָׁעָה רוֹאָה אוֹתוֹ, עַל אַחַת כַּמָּה וְכַמָּה. וּבְכָל יוֹם וָיוֹם מְשַׁדַּלְתּוֹ בִדְבָרִים, וְעָמַד בְּיִצְרוֹ. מִנַּיִן, מִמַּה שֶּׁקָּרְאוּ בְּעִנְיַן וַתִּשָּׂא אֵשֶׁת אֲדֹנָיו.
> Our sages inform us that on one occasion Potiphar’s wife assembled a number of Egyptian women so that they might see how very handsome Joseph was. But before she summoned Joseph she gave each of them an ethrog and a knife. When they saw Joseph’s handsome countenance, they cut their hands. She said to them: “If this can happen to you, who see him only once, how much more so does it happen to me, who must look at him constantly.” Each day she strove to entice him with words, but he suppressed his evil inclination. Whence do we know this? From what we read in the section: His master’s wife cast her eyes upon him (Gen. 39:7).

Shout-out to Shmosel for finding rav chaim vital.

It starts from [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27ar_Ma%27amarei_Razal,_Tractate_Shabbat.12). I'll edit it later

Comment: Great, thanks? Is there any source for her placing some collar chain around his neck that kept his face forward so he couldn’t look down?

Comment: Do you remember which shiur? That might help someone get more details

Comment: @CuriousYid Not sure what the original source is, but it's referenced in my link above.

Comment: @shmosel under what Masechet is it under and where exactly? Not really good at navigating Hebrew sites lol

Comment: @Shababnik I mean here’s the clip if you want https://youtu.be/IS5R_eOTrRc?si=uKbUaU3Y3efB6ZTS it was just a small shiur about shmiras einayim so the point was if Yosef was punished for a tiny glance in the reincarnate for of Rabbi Yishmael, how much more so we should be careful (though i know other midrashim say he was mamash on the bed with eishes potiphar so surely he must’ve also looked at her then  and not only in this moment with the knives)

Comment: Sorry, bad link: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A8%D7%96%22%D7%9C/%D7%A9%22%D7%A1#%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA

Comment: It's from R' Chaim Vital, with his son's commentary. Here's a partial translation: *He looked at her when she put a shackle on his neck, which caused him to have an emission. Even though it was involuntary, Hashem is exacting with his pious followers, so he had to be reincarnated amongst the Ten Martyrs.*